# Laravel 5.4 : ReflectionException in Container.php line 749: Class App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ImageGalleryController does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I'm fed up with this error, used a admin and user login project and got this error.

Laravel 5.4 : ReflectionException in Container.php line 749: Class App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ImageGalleryController does not exist

please look into my files.

***This is the Screenshot of the error:***
[image]

***Routes for Gallery Upload:***

```js
Route::get('gallery-upload', 'ImageGalleryController@index');
Route::post('/gallery-upload', 'ImageGalleryController@upload');
   
Route::delete('/gallery-upload/{id}', 'ImageGalleryController@destroy');
```

***Controller File:***

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\ImageGallery;





class ImageGalleryController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Listing Of images gallery
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

  


    public function index()
    {
     $images = ImageGallery::get();
     return view('gallery-upload',compact('images'));
    }

     public function img()
    {
        $images = ImageGallery::get();
        return view('gallery',compact('images'));
    }
    // /**
    //  * Upload image function
    //  *
    //  * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     
    public function upload(Request $request)
    {
     $this->validate($request, [
      'title' => 'required',
            'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        ]);

        $input['image'] = time().'.'.$request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $request->image->move(public_path('images'), $input['image']);

        $input['title'] = $request->title;
        ImageGallery::create($input);

     return back()
      ->with('success','Image Uploaded successfully.');
    }

    /**
     * Remove Image function
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
     ImageGallery::find($id)->delete();
     return back()
      ->with('success','Image removed successfully.'); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Had you create `ImageGalleryController` in `Admin` directory?? I am sure there is namespace issue!

Comment: There is no route for admin/ImageGalleryController, Then how can came this error.. Class App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ImageGalleryController does not exist,
This is namespace issue..

Comment: yes i have added the namespace.

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

Comment: You need to add `App\Http\Controllers\ImageGalleryController` instead of `App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ImageGalleryController`. Then try it!

Comment: ImageGalleryController is in app\http\controller\admin..?

Comment: use php artisan route:list to see what namespace the app is using for the controller

Answer (score 1):

Route File

```
Route::get('gallery-upload', 'Admin\ImageGalleryController@index');
Route::post('/gallery-upload', 'Admin\ImageGalleryController@upload');

Route::delete('/gallery-upload/{id}', 'Admin\ImageGalleryController@destroy');
```

Controller File :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\ImageGallery;

class ImageGalleryController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Listing Of images gallery
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

    public function index()
    {
        $images = ImageGallery::get();
        return view('gallery-upload',compact('images'));
    }

     public function img()
    {
        $images = ImageGallery::get();
        return view('gallery',compact('images'));
    }
    // /**
    //  * Upload image function
    //  *
    //  * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response

    public function upload(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required',
            'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        ]);

        $input['image'] = time().'.'.$request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $request->image->move(public_path('images'), $input['image']);

        $input['title'] = $request->title;
        ImageGallery::create($input);

        return back()
            ->with('success','Image Uploaded successfully.');
    }

    /**
     * Remove Image function
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        ImageGallery::find($id)->delete();
        return back()
            ->with('success','Image removed successfully.');    
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your namespace looks like it's wrong, I don't see Admin in it anywhere, which is what the application is looking for.

```
App\Http\Controllers\ImageGalleryController
```

not

```
App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ImageGalleryController
```

Comment: changed the namesapce to Admin... 

now i got this new error...

FatalErrorException in ImageGalleryController.php line 14:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Controller' not found

Comment: you'll need to run composer dumpautoload or php artisan optimize to regenerate the autoloaded class files.

Comment: You have to add it in Route as well
`Route::post('/gallery-upload', 'Admin\ImageGalleryController@upload');`
And also you have to change namespace in ImageGalleryController

`namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;`